# Exact Cover by 3-Sets variation: Partition Into Exact Covers by 3-Sets

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, np-complete, exact-cover

In the Exact Cover by 3-Sets problem, we are given a set $X = \{x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_{3n}\}$ and a family of subsets $F = \{\{x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}, x_{i_3}\}\}$ of 3-element subsets of $X$.
The question is then whether there exists a family of subsets $F'\subseteq F$ that forms an exact cover of $X$.

It is known that the problem remains NP-hard under some restrictions, e.g., to instances in which each element appears in exactly three subsets and $\lvert F_i\cap F_j\rvert\leq 1$ for all $F_i, F_j\in F$. (See [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20386/restriction-of-exact-cover-by-3-sets) answer and its referenced paper.)

I would like to modify the problem in a slightly different way: the only restriction on the input is that we know that each element appears in exactly three subsets. The question, however, is this: can the family $F$ be partitioned into three disjoint families $F_1, F_2, F_3$ such that each $F_i$ is an exact cover?

Is this problem already known to be NP-hard/polynomial-time solvable? Another way to view it would be to consider a graph with vertices corresponding to subsets and edges being added if the respective subsets have a non-empty intersection. The problem then asks whether the graph is 3-colorable. Has 3-coloring (or k-coloring) perhaps been studied on this class of set-intersection graphs?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/152290/755

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem of hyperedge coloring of a 3-regular 3-uniform hypergraph (with 3 colors) is reducible to this problem and vice versa, where the set X is corresponds to the vertex set V and each member of the set F is corresponds to a hyperedge. Then, it is as hard as that problem.